# How much electricity could be generated by cloths made of thermocouples?

Tags: thermodynamics

Lets say that we made a glove, shirt, pants and a hat out of the most effective thermocouple material available today.  How much electricity would be generated by each, by a healthy person, on a cool day (98 degrees F vrs 79 degrees F?)

Comment: 79 degF is hardly a "cool" day in many places.  Normal office temp is 68-72 degF, for example.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, figure out what the limit is due to the Carnot efficiency.  The Carnot efficiency is the maximum possible work that can be extracted from heat flow.  It is Tdiff / Thot.

You have Thot = 98°F = 310°K, and Tcold = 79°F = 299°K, so Tdiff = 11°K.

11°K / 310°K = 3.5%

That's the maximum theoretical portion of the heat flow that can be converted to work, given your parameters.  In the case of a human giving off 30 W of heat, that leaves 1.1 W maximum theoretical that can be converted to electric from.  Real heat engines, like thermopiles, of course have their own real inefficiencies.  Due to the engineering difficulties, you'd be lucky to get a few 10s of mW.

Comment: around 20 mW for the entire body?